# Iterm2 on-screen CR/LF?

Tags: iterm2

What are these arrows with numbers that show up in my iTerm2 terminal window, just next the right margin?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This is nothing to do with iTerm2.

This is your *shell*.  You've fairly obviously got your shell configured to display the exit status of the last command in `$RPROMPT` in red if that exit status wasn't zero.

Comment: I'm using ZSH and oh-my-zsh; it looks like this is a function of the theme I'm using ("sunrise").